# What starting conditions for two harmonic oscillators will cause an elliptic path?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

I have the two following equations:

$$y(t) = A\cos \left( \sqrt\frac{2k}{m}t-\phi_y \right)$$

$$x(t) = B\cos \left( \sqrt\frac{2k}{m}t-\phi_x \right)$$

I need to find the starting conditions so that the "curves" will move in an ellipse, where it's main axis is on one of the major axis $(x,y)$.

I'd appreciate a hint. I understand it has to do something with $\phi_{x,y}$, but I can't seem to find anything related at the moment.

Comment: for most starting conditions the path will be an ellipse.  It will only the the special cases are that the path is a circle (eccentricity 0), or a line segment.  It will trace over a line segment if $\phi_x = \phi_y$.  One way to force it onto a circular path is if $A=B$ and $|\phi_x - \phi_y| = 90^\circ$

Comment: need sine and cosine to parametrize ellipse. Doug is on point.

Comment: @DougM Is there any way to force elliptic?

Comment: Choose $|\phi_x - \phi_y| = 90^\circ$ and $A \ne B$  There is probably something along the lines of $(\phi_x-\phi_y)\ne \tan^{-1} \frac AB$ that would do it in a very general sense.